# PS4 gift card online purchase asked for photo ID

Tags: privacy, ids

I purchased ps4 gift card online and they asked for ID verification. Which I have to take a photo of my ID front and back and a selfie. Is that safe and can they do anything with this information? I couldn't say no because they already received my money and whenever I send an email saying why do you need that they reply with the same email asking for the photo ID verification. Their website is giftcardsupply.
I just want to know is it safe?

Comment: It's most likely a fraud prevention mechanism. Depending on the country or region you're in, they can not process this kind of information (EU). A payment should be considered sufficient. Did you pay by credit card? Because that could be the issue.

Comment: No i paid by paypal. But they already received the money, why would a fraud pay them?